# Is possible create reorder after created invoice of the order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice, reorder

How can I edit my order after the invoice is created? The product price needs to change after the invoice is created. Is it possible?

How can I reorder after the invoice is created?

Comment: Which price you need to change? please provide full details

Comment: i need to edit my products price after created invoice.

Comment: https://snag.gy/uzTSxg.jpg

Comment: @John : is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it from the UI.
And there is a reason why.
Once an invoice is created, the data on it should never change.
You can void the invoice and "Edit" the order.
By edit, what will happen is:

- the order will be canceled.
- a new order will be created in which you can edit the product prices, save the order and create a new invoice with the new prices.

Comment: okay,  i am using Magento ver : 1.9.2.3, how can i void my invoice?

Comment: As you told order will be canceled, may i know after the new order created id like 33344455-1 or it completely create fresh order like 33344456

Comment: it creates a `-1` order. And about the invoice voiding. You can create a credit memo for the created invoice.

Comment: i just created credit memo by click refund offline -> https://snag.gy/TVslBO.jpg ,,,,,, then how can i edit order -> https://snag.gy/dKhAic.jpg

Comment: As you told, "You can void the invoice and "Edit" the order",,, where I can edit an order after created credit memo.

Comment: go to the original order page and see if there is an edit button. It should be there. If for some reason is not there, you can hit the reorder button and it will create a new order that does not have the `-1` at the end of the order number.

Comment: yes marius, i have 2 points of doubts, first one,  there is no option for edit after created credit memo, and second one, how can i create reorder with -1.

Comment: Edit option not available after created credit memo, and then reorder make my order new, i need -1.

Comment: Then, I'm sorry. I have no other ideas.

Comment: Really thank you bro,, thanks for your time.

Comment: @ Marius: I found a lot of option for migrating from M1 to M2, Which method is best for migrate from M1 to M2? And one more doubt, after migrate where I should focus on required changes?

Comment: any suggestions on this question please https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7/266737#266737